# `Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage` causing slow boot-times.

Tags: boot, ssd

My boot-up takes around a minute as it just gets stuck at `Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage`. I'm running Ubuntu on an SSD. How can I resolve this?

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2994 has some hints. Even though this is about a freeze, there really is no difference from a user perspective between a very long boot and a freeze. Might be worthwhile debugging the boot process. The takeaway is that this message may have nothing to do with the what is actually increasing your boot times.

Comment: See the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1094543

Comment: You can check this detailed answer for a similar question [askubuntu.com/a/1094543/163270](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094543/163270)