# What is the use of systemd-journal-flush.service?

Tags: boot, systemd, services

It slows my system boot time.

Can i disable it?

What will happen if i disable it on boot?

I am using Ubuntu version 18.04.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `systemd-journal-flush.service` asks the journal daemon to flush any log data stored in /run/log/journal into /var/log/journal, if `persistent` storage is enabled. In case you have (already) huge log files, this will result in slower booting. Further, the disk (with `/var/log`) has to be mounted in a writable modus to do so.

To sum it up: huge old log files, which are checked during boot and the appending of new log data results in slower boot time.

To check the journalctl log size type

```
journalctl --disk-usage
```

In order to get the time and disk space information of flush processing, enter the following command

```
journalctl -b --unit systemd-journald
```

The corresponding output will look like

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-12-08 00:40:23 CET, end at Mon 2018-12-10 19:40:27 CET. --
Dec 10 12:51:38 ubuntu01 systemd-journald[479]: Journal started
Dec 10 12:51:38 ubuntu01 systemd-journald[479]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/265c93c062bf4c8da41abfe2ae793452) is 4.7M, max 38.3M, 33.5M free.
Dec 10 12:51:38 ubuntu01 systemd-journald[479]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 7.066904s for 132 entries.
Dec 10 12:51:38 ubuntu01 systemd-journald[479]: System journal (/var/log/journal/265c93c062bf4c8da41abfe2ae793452) is 128.0M, max 256.0M, 128M free.
```

#### You can either

- Disable the service (not recommended)

  Then it is possible that not all log data is written to disk; annoying when debugging boot faults. Journald is a fundamental service in **systemd** Linux and many other services depends on it.
- Verify the journal file for internal consistency:

  ```
    journalctl --verify
  ```

  Look out that every journal shows up **PASS**.
- Use a `journalctl --vacuum` command

  From `journalctl -h`

  > --vacuum-size=BYTES     Reduce disk usage below specified size
  > --vacuum-files=INT      Leave only the specified number of journal files
  > --vacuum-time=TIME      Remove journal files older than specified time

  Hence do a

  ```
    sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=1G --vacuum-time=5d --vacuum-files=5
  ```
- Change  storage type of `systemd-journal-flush.service`

  First check your storage type with:

  ```
       systemctl cat systemd-journal-flush.service  | grep -i storage
  ```

  From `man journald.conf`

  > **Storage=**
  >
  > Controls where to store journal data.
  > One of "volatile", "persistent", "auto" and "none".
  >
  > If "**volatile**", journal log data will be stored only in memory, i.e. below the /run/log/journal hierarchy
  > (which is created if needed).
  >
  > If "**persistent**", data will be stored
  > preferably on disk, i.e. below the /var/log/journal hierarchy (which is created if needed), with a fallback to /run/log/journal (which is created if needed), during early boot and if the disk is not writable.
  >
  > "**auto**" is similar to "persistent" but the directory /var/log/journal is not created if needed, so that its existence controls where log data goes.
  >
  > "**none**" turns off all storage, all log data received will be dropped.
  > Forwarding to other targets, such as the console, the kernel
  > log buffer, or a syslog socket will still work however. Defaults to
  > "auto".

  Edit the file

  sudo nano /etc/systemd/journald.conf

  In the journal section uncomment and alter:

  Storage=auto
  SystemMaxUse=200M
  SystemKeepFree=1G
  SystemMaxFileSize=1G
  SystemMaxFiles=5

### Recommendation

I recommend limiting the size of the **SystemMaxFileSize** key to 50MB -->

```
SystemMaxFileSize=50M
```

Finally, in case your Ubuntu is not running on an important server, I suggest changing the data storage to volatile:

```
Storage=volatile
```

`SystemMaxUse` control how much disk space the journal may use up at most.

`SystemKeepFree` and `RuntimeKeepFree` control how much disk space systemd-journald shall leave free for other uses. systemd-journald will respect both limits and use the smaller of the two values.

If you run the boot in debug mode and trace the system calls (`strace`) you may found out that the flush writing has a very poor i/o performance. In my case it was unclear why. Maybe some kernel messages spam the log file (note that after 10000 messages the unit is blocked per default, but journald has to manage this, which maybe cause the poor performance). In that case step over the messages and search for errors, which haven't necessarily marked as errors.

```
journalctl -b --output short-monotonic
```

and

```
journalctl -b -p 1..4 --output short-monotonic
```

The `--output short-monotonic`flag prints the time steps in contrast to the default UTC time.

Finally, remove the old log files by

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/journal
```

Save & reboot.

Comment: I don't see why huge log file would slow the boot ? it flushes the log in /run/log/journal but that's only the log since the last boot

Comment: I'am not absolute sure. It could also be the (useless?) dependency of systemd-user-sessions-flush.service on systemd-user-sessions.service (seehttps://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/10502). However, I experienced that limiting the log file to less than 1GB speeds up boot time. I read through the systemd/journal/* code, but didn't found sth interesting.

Comment: Maybe due to de-/compression (lz4)? Further log data doesn't simply get streamd into the file; it gets journaled and  a hash table for faster searching modified, objects, ...

Comment: I think a comment on how the journal files and /var/log files relate might be useful; I'm not clear on that but it seems to me that the journal is active logging and when it's flushed that is writing the active data to the disk in the normal /var/log files?

Comment: you are right, but during booting data cannot be written to disk, since the disk has to be mounted first.

Comment: relevant link https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4422

Comment: its definitely slowing things down. seems like insufficient testing is done on this by the developers to deliver safe defaults.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The strange thing is I have no slow down with archlinux, fedora and debian. So it seems to be ubuntu related.

Comment: @abu_bua I experience slowdown with Fedora

Comment: What do you mean with slowdown

Answer (score 4):

According to this post from the [systemd developer homepage](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/10502), you can fix it by changing the **Unit file**.

To do so, open `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journal-flush.service`, eg

```
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journal-flush.service
```

and change the **Before dependency** from

```
 Before=systemd-user-sessions.service systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
```

to

```
￼ Before=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
```

This fix will be automatically altered for systemd versions > v240.

Don't forget to save the file.