# boot startup speedup Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04

i have this problem (startup take more than one and half minute ~ 1:35 sec)  and i did a lot of search but i cann't find any things to solve it (i have processor=intel core i3, ram=4G , swap=9G) and my boot info it is:

```
~$ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 10.299s (kernel) + 49.706s (userspace) = 1min 6ms
graphical.target reached after 49.694s in userspace
```

and graphical analyze are

```
~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain graphical.target
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @49.694s
└─multi-user.target @49.693s
  └─mysql.service @39.610s +10.082s
    └─network.target @39.607s
      └─wpa_supplicant.service @34.142s +5.464s
        └─dbus.service @28.807s
          └─basic.target @28.749s
            └─sockets.target @28.749s
              └─snapd.socket @28.747s +1ms
                └─sysinit.target @28.719s
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @28.477s +240ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @27.622s +716ms
                      └─systemd-journal-flush.service @5.195s +22.426s
                        └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.389s +803ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @4.354s
                            └─system.slice @4.354s
                              └─-.slice @4.334s
```

Comment: The storage device is probably a 5400rpm HDD. Nothing wrong with that, but they tend to be rather slow. Get an SSD to have quick boot times.

Comment: Even an HDD shouldn't take that long to boot. Maybe this answer can help with the flushing part: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Disabled NetworkManager-wait-online.service and that will cut down on some of the time.  Otherwise if you can update to 18.10 that is what solved it for me.