# How to reduce login time of Kubuntu?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, login, logo

When I start my laptop, a blue screen with Kubuntu logo keeps loading for long time before the login screen appears. Because of that, boot time increased significantly. Is there any way to remove that logo screen or reduce time for appearance of that logo before login screen appears?

After I provide my credentials on login screen, Its normal. Only issue is with the blue logo screen which appears before login screen and stays for long time.

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 LTS with Plasma Shell 5.12.7.

Please find my boot.log file here: https://send.firefox.com/download/c0cc9425127d944b/#xy3FpDkqRCLPOLyWSwxjyQ

navi@navi-ubuntu:~$ systemd-analyze

Startup finished in 11.771s (firmware) + 4.164s (loader) + 7.074s (kernel) + 56.471s (userspace) = 1min 19.481s
graphical.target reached after 54.946s in userspace

navi@navi-ubuntu:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

````
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @54.946s

└─multi-user.target @54.946s

  └─smbd.service @54.622s +323ms

    └─nmbd.service @47.195s +7.426s

      └─network-online.target @47.182s

        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @39.672s +7.509s

          └─NetworkManager.service @33.024s +6.633s

            └─dbus.service @32.239s

              └─basic.target @32.185s

                └─sockets.target @32.185s

                  └─snapd.socket @32.117s +67ms

                    └─sysinit.target @32.116s

                      └─systemd-timesyncd.service @31.935s +178ms

                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @31.415s +492ms

                          └─systemd-journal-flush.service @5.434s +25.980s

                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.622s +811ms

                              └─systemd-journald.socket @4.620s

                                └─system.slice @4.620s

                                  └─-.slice @4.611s```
````

Comment: What version of Kubuntu and Plasma (edit your question to answer)?

Comment: kubuntu 18.04 LTS & Plasmashell 5.12.7

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete, properly-formatted output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: Added the systemd-analyze output and boot.log file link

Comment: This is really not a bad time for boot.  One process, systemd-journal-flush is taking a while, and you might examine [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like boot process gets stuck on something. Contents of /var/log/boot.log might help. File  can be viewed only with sudo privileges.