# Ubuntu 20.04 boots for multiple minutes after installing Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 (No upgrade but installed from scratch) and all was well. Ubuntu booted within 10s or something. Now I installed Windows next to Ubuntu and therefore installt VirtualBox (for creating the boot USB stick). Appearently something now slows my boot times down by ages and to me it appears that it is "systemd-journal-flush.service" as the next operations starts 1:30 minutes later (it looks like this every time I boot).

systemd-analyze critical-chain gives me:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 37.905s
└─multi-user.target @1min 37.904s
  └─virtualbox.service @1min 37.817s +87ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 37.814s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 31.178s +6.634s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 31.005s +172ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 31.000s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.988s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.988s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.987s +713us
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.982s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1min 30.708s +273ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1min 30.459s +243ms
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @641ms +248ms
                          └─systemd-journald.service @253ms +387ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @249ms
                              └─-.mount @246ms
                                └─system.slice @246ms
                                  └─-.slice @246ms
```

systemd-analyze blame outputs:

```
6.634s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                      >
3.554s apt-daily.service                                                       >
1.088s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                     >
1.079s snap-discord-109.mount                                                  >
1.077s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-768B\x2dA0A2.service                   >
1.071s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-33.mount                                  >
1.020s snap-spotify-41.mount                                                   >
 999ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-cf833b52\x2dfd6d\x2d4d76\x2dbb08\x2dc2f>
 982ms dev-sda3.device                                                         >
 971ms dev-loop1.device                                                        >
 954ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-24.mount                                  >
 879ms dev-loop2.device                                                        >
 849ms dev-loop3.device                                                        >
 849ms dev-loop4.device                                                        >
 841ms fwupd.service                                                           >
 785ms systemd-logind.service                                                  >
 726ms dev-loop6.device                                                        >
 719ms dev-loop5.device                                                        >
 681ms dev-loop7.device                                                        >
 630ms snapd.service                                                           >
 613ms dev-loop8.device                                                        >
 574ms dev-loop9.device                                                        >
 517ms snap-skype-128.mount                                                    >
 483ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                             >
 473ms snap-core18-1754.mount                                                  >
 422ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount                                            >
 421ms snap-snap\x2dstore-454.mount                                            >
 420ms snap-snapd-7264.mount                                                   >
 412ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                  >
 387ms systemd-journald.service                                                >
 383ms upower.service                                                          >
 354ms udisks2.service                                                         >
 353ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-95.mount                                    >
 352ms systemd-resolved.service                                                >
 311ms gpu-manager.service                                                     >
 273ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                               >
 256ms apparmor.service                                                        >
 256ms ModemManager.service                                                    >
 248ms systemd-journal-flush.service                                           >
 243ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                          >
 235ms dev-loop0.device                                                        >
 234ms accounts-daemon.service                                                 >
 234ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount                                 >
 228ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                 >
 225ms plymouth-read-write.service                                             >
 216ms console-setup.service                                                   >
 186ms snap-core18-1705.mount                                                  >
 182ms polkit.service                                                          >
 176ms avahi-daemon.service                                                    >
 172ms NetworkManager.service                                                  >
 171ms bluetooth.service                                                       >
 170ms dev-loop10.device                                                       >
 146ms gdm.service                                                             >
 144ms apport-autoreport.service                                               >
 135ms switcheroo-control.service                                              >
 124ms dev-loop11.device                                                       >
 113ms snap-core-9066.mount                                                    >
 113ms thermald.service                                                        >
 110ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                  >
 109ms apport.service                                                          >
 102ms grub-common.service                                                     >
  99ms secureboot-db.service                                                   >
  97ms user@125.service                                                        >
  96ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                    >
  90ms user@1000.service                                                       >
  87ms virtualbox.service                                                      >
  86ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                            >
  72ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                            >
  66ms systemd-udevd.service                                                   >
  62ms rsyslog.service                                                         >
  60ms keyboard-setup.service                                                  >
  52ms colord.service                                                          >
  43ms dev-loop12.device                                                       >
  43ms snapd.apparmor.service                                                  >
  43ms systemd-modules-load.service                                            >
  43ms ssh.service                                                             >
  42ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b29d1530\x2dfb1f\x2d407e\x2dbf11\x2dde8c1359c9e0.swa>
  42ms nvidia-persistenced.service                                             >
  38ms pppd-dns.service                                                        >
  34ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                >
  32ms systemd-random-seed.service                                             >
  30ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                          >
  26ms alsa-restore.service                                                    >
  22ms kerneloops.service                                                      >
  21ms snapd.seeded.service                                                    >
  17ms modprobe@drm.service                                                    >
  17ms openvpn.service                                                         >
  15ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                                            >
  15ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                              >
  13ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                           >
  12ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                  >
  12ms home.mount                                                              >
  12ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                           >
  12ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                             >
  11ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                     >
  11ms boot-efi.mount                                                          >
  11ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                      >
  11ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                        >
  10ms systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service                    >
  10ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                  >
  10ms plymouth-quit-wait.service                                              >
  10ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                >
   8ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                               >
   8ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                    >
   8ms vboxweb.service                                                         >
   6ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                    >
   5ms ufw.service                                                             >
   5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                           >
   4ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                 >
   4ms setvtrgb.service                                                        >
   3ms dev-loop13.device                                                       >
 713us snapd.socket                                                            >
 260us clean-mount-point@media-simon-123GB\x20USB\x20Drive.service
```

My system's hardware (sudo lshw -short):

```
H/W path                 Device     Class          Description
===============================================================
                                    system         20AWS3JX00 (LENOVO_MT_20AW_BU
/0                                  bus            20AWS3JX00
/0/0                                processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ C
/0/0/2                              memory         32KiB L1 Cache
/0/0/3                              memory         256KiB L2 Cache
/0/0/4                              memory         6MiB L3 Cache
/0/1                                memory         32KiB L1 Cache
/0/5                                memory         16GiB System memory
/0/5/0                              memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchron 160
/0/5/1                              memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchron 160
/0/35                               memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/100                              bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core 
/0/100/1                            bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core 
/0/100/1.1                          bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core 
/0/100/1.1/0                        display        GK208M [GeForce GT 730M]
/0/100/2                            display        4th Gen Core Processor Integr
/0/100/3                            multimedia     Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core 
/0/100/14                           bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/14/0              usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/3            scsi6      storage        Ultra Fit
/0/100/14/0/3/0.0.0      /dev/sdb   disk           123GB Ultra Fit
/0/100/14/0/3/0.0.0/0    /dev/sdb   disk           123GB 
/0/100/14/0/3/0.0.0/0/1  /dev/sdb1  volume         114GiB Windows NTFS disk
/0/100/14/0/6                       input          2.4G Mouse
/0/100/14/0/7                       generic        VFS 5011 fingerprint sensor
/0/100/14/0/b                       communication  Bluetooth interface
/0/100/14/0/c                       multimedia     Integrated Camera
/0/100/14/1              usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                           communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/16.3                         communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/19                enp0s25    network        Ethernet Connection I217-LM
/0/100/1a                           bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/1a/1              usb1       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1                       bus            USB-Hub
/0/100/1b                           multimedia     8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/1c                           bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/1c/0                         generic        RTS5227 PCI Express Card Read
/0/100/1c.1                         bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/1c.1/0            wlp4s0     network        Wireless 7260
/0/100/1d                           bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/1d/1              usb2       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1                       bus            USB-Hub
/0/100/1f                           bridge         QM87 Express LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2              scsi0      storage        8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0        /dev/sda   disk           360GB INTEL SSDSC2BF36
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/1      /dev/sda1  volume         952MiB Windows FAT disk
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/2      /dev/sda2  volume         14GiB Linux swap disk
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/3      /dev/sda3  volume         27GiB EXT4 disk
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/4      /dev/sda4  volume         186GiB EXT4 disk
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/5      /dev/sda5  volume         105GiB Windows NTFS disk
/0/100/1f.3                         bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
/0/2                                system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/3                                system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/4                                system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/6                                generic        PnP device LEN0071
/0/7                                generic        PnP device LEN0036
/0/8                                generic        PnP device SMO1200
/1                                  power          Batt Device Name
```

I am aware that reinstalling is an option. Please only answer if you have a different idea or want to give some details as to how to reinstall more specifically.
Thank you everybody in advance.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you very much, I guess this will help quite some people. I didn't see your reply though and already reinstalled Ubuntu. It replaced only itself and didn't touch Windows. But now, even after installing every app I had installed before, My boot times are down to only a few seconds again. Thanks for helping nonetheless.

Comment: no problem :) glad you got it working