# Slow boot time on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, systemd, boot-time

I've just installed Ubuntu on a new build PC and I'm consistently experiencing long boot times of well over 2 minutes. I saw a lot of advice to use systemd-analyze, but wasn't sure how to interpret it for my situation. I've included the output of `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`, below. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.372s (firmware) + 5.319s (loader) + 3.706s (kernel) + 2min 22.911s (userspace) = 2min 39.309s
```

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 22.683s
└─multi-user.target @2min 22.683s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @1min 17.297s +497ms
    └─snapd.service @32.501s +44.790s
      └─basic.target @32.359s
        └─sockets.target @32.359s
          └─snapd.socket @32.358s +662us
            └─sysinit.target @32.251s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @31.837s +414ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @30.880s +915ms
                  └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.100s +26.779s
                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @3.866s +165ms
                      └─systemd-journald.socket @3.526s
                        └─system.slice @3.524s
                          └─-.slice @3.524s
```

-----Edit-----
Hardware Specs:

- Processor: Intel Core i7-6700K 4 GHz Quad-Core
- CPU Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO 82.9 CFM Sleeve Bearing
- Motherboard: Asus B150M-C Micro ATX LGA1151
- Memory: Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16
- Storage: Seagate BarraCuda 4 TB 2.5" 5400RPM Internal HDD
- Power supply: be quiet! System Power 9 600 W 80+ Bronze Certified ATX

-----Edit 2-----
Output of `systemd-anaylze critical-chain` after running `sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd` and `sudo reboot`.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 30.725s
└─multi-user.target @1min 30.725s
  └─kerneloops.service @1min 396ms +66ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 389ms
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @47.348s +13.040s
        └─NetworkManager.service @38.520s +8.823s
          └─dbus.service @38.517s
            └─basic.target @38.479s
              └─sockets.target @38.479s
                └─uuidd.socket @38.479s
                  └─sysinit.target @38.465s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @38.109s +356ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @37.043s +1.028s
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.294s +32.747s
                          └─systemd-journald.service @3.840s +453ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @3.837s
                              └─-.mount @3.835s
                                └─system.slice @3.835s
                                  └─-.slice @3.835s
```

Comment: Hello there. Could you provide a bit of detail about your system? Which CPU are you using? How much memory? Things like that. This will help provide some context around why you might be having issues.

Comment: It's a well known fact that snaps have a considerable impact on bootup time. Do you have many snaps installed, and are you booting from an old (spinning) HDD?

Comment: You're having issue with systemd-journal-flush.service. It takes about 27 seconds to finish. Have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service). You might get an idea going through the answers. Another major impact is on snapd (45 seconds). It's snapcraft package manager daemon. You can try removing it by issuing `sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`. Check if this reduces boot time by at least 1 minute. Your machine's hardware details would help us identify the problem further.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick responses. I've added the hardware specs to the post.

Comment: Looking at the spec, 2+ minutes of boot time is unexpected. 4TB 5200 RPM HDD might not be a faster hard drive but it shouldn't be more than 1 minute. Try removing snapd as I mentioned above then post another log of systemd-analyze

Comment: Thanks @JijoJoseph, after running `sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd` it boots a bit faster. It's down from ~2:10 to ~1:40. Still well over a minute, but a big improvement. I've updated the post with the new output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ArturMeinild I'm not even sure what a snap is. I've not installed anything beyond the OS at this point.

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1166486/968501) can help.

Comment: And this for the long time systemd-journal-flush.service takes: https://askubuntu.com/q/1094389/1037709

Comment: In `/etc/default/grub` replace the value of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash debug --verbose"`

then run: `$sudo update-grub`

This will enable printing of debugging information during the boot sequence. This should inform next time you boot what operation in the boot sequence stalls the critical-chain.

Comment: mostly these type of boot delays will come due to something need to get mouunted while booting without actually system having it. in systemd-analyze critical-chain, it is clearly showing boot gaps. will you paste your `/var/log/boot.log` file? something you can look up for like "timed out waitng for the device..." or "dependency failed for...." in that file