# Why is Ubuntu 22.04 taking a lot of time to boot up after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, 22.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Now while booting there are many errors like "Ubuntu failed to mount". After some time it boots up and works fine but my issue is it takes a lot of time to boot.

I checked all the answers I could find relevant in this forum but nothing seemed to work for me.

I did boot-repair and got a pastebin info about my boot file.
Here is the link : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/T3QdHdSGTW/
can you please tell me what is the issue in this ?

EDIT 1 : output of cat /etc/fstab

```
 /etc/fstab: static file system information.

     Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
     device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
     that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    
     <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
     / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=ef07b47f-a6f2-4362-ab9c-13246ce605e3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
    /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
    /mnt/4GiB.swap swap swap defaults 0 0
    /swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

EDIT 2 : I removed last 2 lines and some progress there but still it is very slow. Also, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316770/why-ubuntu-20-04-userspace-boot-time-is-so-slow) says to remove everything in

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04) says to add noresume in the quotes. I actually have

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

What should I do ? Should I remove all these in quotes or should I add noresume in it ?

> sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain

Output :

```
graphical.target @1min 42.959s
└─multi-user.target @1min 42.959s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @42.999s +59.958s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @42.948s +46ms
      └─network.target @42.392s
        └─NetworkManager.service @32.346s +10.045s
          └─dbus.service @32.342s
            └─basic.target @32.220s
              └─sockets.target @32.220s
                └─snapd.socket @32.217s +2ms
                  └─sysinit.target @31.886s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @31.356s +527ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @29.483s +1.728s
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @8.970s +20.509s
                          └─systemd-journald.service @8.340s +628ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @8.329s
                              └─system.slice @8.296s
                                └─-.slice @8.296s
```

```
systemd-analyze && systemd-analyze blame
Startup finished in 4.083s (kernel) + 1min 43.042s (userspace) = 1min 47.126s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 42.959s in userspace
59.958s plymouth-quit-wait.service
55.186s mysql.service
35.100s snapd.service
25.223s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
20.509s systemd-journal-flush.service
20.205s networkd-dispatcher.service
20.068s cups.service
19.459s apache2.service
18.274s ModemManager.service
17.765s accounts-daemon.service
17.483s udisks2.service
17.064s dev-sda1.device
13.595s user@1000.service
12.173s ufw.service
11.946s dev-loop3.device
11.859s dev-loop1.device
11.527s dev-loop12.device
11.005s dev-loop9.device
10.946s ua-timer.service
10.758s dev-loop6.device
10.738s dev-loop13.device
10.379s polkit.service
10.378s power-profiles-daemon.service
```

Now what should I do ?
Thank you!

Comment: please [edit] your question and show us `cat /etc/fstab` from your installed ubuntu. I see two swapfles and a Mountpoint /mnt/4GiB for swap?.

Comment: Sir, I added the output of the query, can you please check, Thank you

Comment: Remove the last 2 lines. And make a reboot.

Comment: just to be completely sure last 2 lines as in " /mnt/4GiB.swap swap swap defaults 0 0
    /swapfile none swap sw 0 0" ?

Comment: One more thing sir, can you please tell me what seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: Sorry I'm on mobile `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and remove the last 2 entries and only them.

Comment: @squareroot  Your `/etc/fstab` is defining three separate files as swapfiles.   They are, by name `/swapfile` then `/mnt/4GiB.swap` and `/swapfile`.  The verylast entry is redundant, and can be removed without consequence.  The second entry defines an additional swapfile (which I would not have done) and can probably be removed.

Comment: I not that your boot-repair output recommends moving the grub2 files from `sda1` to `sda` and specifies that to do this, you must boot and run the program from a live USB.  Have you tried this?  I would recommend making a backup of any critical data first.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Sir, I have edited my answer please check, thank you.

Comment: @squareroot I don't understand why the plymouth wait services are so slow in responding.  I don't use them myself. But I am told that this is simply waiting for something else in the boot process to finish, and so it is probably masking some other error, such as Ubuntu being upset that the grub2 files are not in the correct location.

Comment: @squareroot  The parameters "quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1" ensure that fewer errors are shown during the boot process (quiet) the pretty Ubuntu logo is displayed during boot (splash) and the computer does not enter an invalid power saving state which may freeze your computer - not everyone needs that parameter.  If you are looking for votes as to what to do, I would suppest booting from a LiveUSB and running boot-repair there choosing the 'recommended options'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I did the following things and found out certain things:

1. Booted from LiveUSB and ran  `boot-repair` and selected recommended options as suggested by @charles-green. It improved the boot time to some extent.
2. Then I rebooted the system a few times and interestingly it improved some more.(as an aside this issue(the slow booting) also happened when I installed 20.04 and after booting a few times it worked fine).
3. I figured the problem may be because of less swap space, so I increased swap space to be equal to the RAM size which is 4GB. This also gave some improvements, although I am not sure swap space is related to this issue or not.
4. One more thing I would like to mention is the problem may be because of slow processor because I have 1.8GHz processor and 4GB RAM

This are the things I have done.I want for some senior person to review this because it is my first answer.Please forgive me for bad grammar, English is not my first language.

If you think answer is not useful, either please make it useful or comment below, I will delete it.

Thank you