# Big /var/log/journal

Tags: 20.04, log, systemd-journald

I have a problem with my ubuntu 20.04 My /vat/log/journal grows to 195G. When I execute the command `$tail -f /var/log/syslog` I see a log repeated and I think this is my problem.

```
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: Invalid password
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: The Secure Boot key you've entered is not 
valid. The password used must be
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: between 8 and 16 characters.
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: Enter a password for Secure Boot. It will 
be asked again after a reboot.
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: Enter the same password again to verify 
you have typed it correctly.
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: Invalid password
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: The Secure Boot key you've entered is not 
valid. The password used must be
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: between 8 and 16 characters.
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: Enter a password for Secure Boot. It will 
be asked again after a reboot.
Sep 20 19:45:11 fanapsoft vboxdrv.sh[6730]: Enter the same password again to verify 
you have typed it correctly.
```

I don't have any idea why this problem occurred. I remember last time when I upgrade ubuntu It wants to set a password for the next reboot but it doesn't get the password after reboot.
Know I can't clear the /var/log/journal and when I run the `$ sudo rm -rf /var/log/journal/*`  nothing happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of systemd-journal-flush.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service)

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/systemd/journald.conf` has a setting to limit the size of `/var/log/journal/*`

```
SystemMaxUse={n}M
```

where `{n}` is the max size.

> `$ sudo rm -rf /var/log/journal/*`  nothing happened.

That is correct. `rm` only reports if it errors out.

You do need to restart your deamon though for it to take effect (or reboot) with `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald.service`

Comment: So what is the correct form? _SystemMaxUse={1000}M_? or _SystemMaxUse=1000M_. That's when an good example is superior to any technical explanations.